# why Handler , Timer , only run once?

Tags: android

I have this code , and I want to run Log.d every 1000 milis , but It only run once .

```
seekView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                    Log.d("WWWW", "www");

                }
            }, 1000);
```

creating handler , timer , ... only run once like this , where is my problem ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To keep it running continuously at an interval of 1 second, you need to call **postDelayed** as nested in your **Run** method again. See the example below:

```
seekView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

  public void run() {
    Log.d("WWWW", "www");

    //calling postdelayed again
    seekView.postDelayed(this, 1000);       //added this line
  }
}, 1000);
```

doing so will keep it calling it self at an interval of 1 second.

Answer (score 3):

Use for repeat:

```
 ... 
class YourTimeTask extends TimerTask {
   public void run() {
    ....
   }
}

...
new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new YourTimerTask(), after, interval);
...
```