# update notification text every second

Tags: java, android

I want to update the text of a notification every second. i wrote this code

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        builder.setContentTitle("Text");
            builder.setContentText("value updated every 1 second");
        }

    }           
}, 1*1000);
```

but the value is not updated every 1 second but only one time. why? how can i do this?

Comment: Check this other stackoverflow [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9850594/why-handler-timer-only-run-once).

Answer (score 1):

Try to use Timers Handler ll invoke one time.

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask task  = new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                updateUI();
            }
        };
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0,1000);
```

put your Handler to separate method

```
public void updateUI(){
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                builder.setContentTitle("Text");
                    builder.setContentText("value updated every 1 second");

            }
        }, 1000);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

his code starts an thread which sleeps 1000 milliseconds every round.

```
Thread t = new Thread() {

  @Override
  public void run() {
    try {
      while (!isInterrupted()) {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
            // update TextView here!
          }
        });
      }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
  }
};

t.start();
```